# Can I cool my toffee in the fridge?

Tags: candy, toffee

I'm making some treacle toffee for tonight but think I've left it too late to cool naturally - will cooling it In the fridge affect the result too much, or just speed the process up nicely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaving any sort of sugar confection in the fridge (as it will out of the fridge also, but to a lesser extent) will soften the sugar after a prolonged period due to the moisture in the air. However, putting it in the fridge for a short period of time will simply speed up the cooling process as you put in your question.

Comment: As it was it hardened nicely in time for the fireworks, so all was well. I shall have to try some more later and out half in the fridge.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid Good, I'm pleased to hear it!